# Why am I getting 'undefined symbol' error for class that is on my build path?

Tags: java, eclipse, build

I have an eclipse project with a third party library on my build path.  I am trying to use a class from this library, which eclipse recognizes (and I can see in the hierarchy of the jar file when I drill down), but when I actually try to build the project I'm getting an 'undefined symbol' error for this type.  I am using other libraries on the build path without issue.  Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Our projects are built with ANT.

Comment: What do you build your project with? Eclipse or something like ant?

Comment: It's not actually on the classpath, or it's missing a dependency, or...? Impossible to know.

Comment: Post some code, where do you get this error?

Comment: The code won't be useful.  I'm just instantiating an object, nothing fancy.  Hitting ctrl-shift-O pulls the import into the file so eclipse knows it is there.

Our environment uses ant build files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question with such a little details.
Here's a few vulnerable points of your build:

1. Ant is using different version of java compiler than Eclipse does.
2. Ant is using different version of the library or doesn't use it at all.
3. Order of your dependencies in your classpath for Ant build is different from one in Eclipse.

More details will get you a better answer.

There are also some existing answered questions to consider. They mainly regarding shared libraries (C++ or else) used in Java applications:

[Undefined Symbol Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867719/undefined-symbol-error)

[Just started C++: Undefined Symbol error on Compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526660/just-started-c-undefined-symbol-error-on-compile)

[shared library compiles, but has undefined symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596271/shared-library-compiles-but-has-undefined-symbols)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will take a look at this.

One other note is that I added classpath validation to my ant build file to check for any conflicts, and there aren't any for this specific class.

Comment: I'm blind it was set as a runtime dependency and not a build dependency.